# HTML Div Positioning with static menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this has probably been spoken about before but I am in need of some expertise.

I have a div tag

```
<div id="body">
   <div id="menu">
   </div>

   <div id="content">
   </div>
</div>
```

what I need is for the menu to float left and be 200px and the content on the right to sit beside it but be 100% or whatever the remainder of the width is?  Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/vBUhD/  Its the best I can do?

Comment: Can you add some image so that I can see and not imaging it.
If you want menu to float left and content sticked to that. Add float:left to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somthing like

```
#menu{
float: left;
width: 200px;
margin-left: -100%;
position: relative;
}

#content {
padding: 0 0 0 220px;
}

#body {
width: 100%;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this done with CSS like this:

```
#body { width: 100%; }

#menu {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: lightGray;
    min-height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: lightBlue;
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/jSUNt/

The content will flow around the menu on the left.

Answer (score 0):

an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AMbRU/

as you can see, just add `float: left` to the menu and apply some kind of clearing technique to the parent